# CSS: Lining Up Buttons Horizontally In A Div Where One Of Them Is In A Form

Tags: css, button, html, alignment

I have a JSP page where there is a row of buttons in their own div at the bottom of a page.  The button at the far left belongs to a form whose end tag,  overlaps the start of the button_bar div.   The button at the far right has its own self contained form.

The buttons line up horizontally, as I like, when I save the JSP as an HTML page ( complete, with css files, etc ).  However, when the content is in a JSP the bottons don't line up horizontally.

Is there anything with CSS I can do to get around this.

**The button div:**

```
<div class="button_bar">


        <div class="button_bar_left_button">     
            <input value="Request More Informtion" name="buttonRequestMoreInformation" type="submit">
        </div>

</form><!-- end form 'f', main form -->    

    <div class="button_bar_left_button">     
        <input value="Start New Search" onclick="location.href='search'" name="buttonSearch" type="button">
    </div>


        <div class="button_bar_right_button">
            <form action="initialRequest" method="post">
                <input name="NextRequest" value="Add Member" type="hidden">
                <input "buttonaddmember"="" value="Add Member" type="submit">
            </form>       
        </div>




</div><!-- end div button_bar -->
```

**The CSS from my style sheet:**

```
/* horizontal button bar */
.button_bar
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align:top;
}

/* put a button on the far right of the above button bar */
.button_bar_right_button
{
    float:right;
    margin-left:1%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
/* put a button on the far left of the above button bar */
.button_bar_left_button
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:1%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

---

**Answer**

---

MODs steveax's comment below helped me solve this problem.  He mentioned that some browsers will insert tags to balance a mistake I was doing.  That led me to making changes that solved the problem.  I would like to accept his second comment ( first comment under the first proposed answer ) as the asnwer.

I moved my form closing tag below the div for the buttons. I also moved the "Add Member" form outside of all of that and changed the "Add Member" button to a plain old button with a call to *.submit for that special form in the onclick. That solved it. I don't see a "accept comment as answer" link/button, but if there is I will give it to you. Thanks much. – Steve just now edit

---

Comment: That's not valid HTML - have you run the page through a [validator](http://validator.nu/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed a piece of your input `"buttonaddmember"=""` as it's not valid. Seems to be horizontally aligned now. Not sure if you intended that.

```
<input "buttonaddmember"="" value="Add Member" type="submit">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6MXuZ/

Or add position:relative on your `button_bar` div, then absolutely position the buttons.

Comment: In addition to that error, he's closing the form tag in the middle of a div (`<div>...</form>...</div>`). Browsers will most likely add a closing div tag right before the closing form tag (`<div>...</div></form>...</div>`) to correct the DOM tree errors, this will lead to unpredictable rendering.

Comment: Christopher, thinks for noticing that.  I must have backspaced out my name attribute.  Fixing it hasn't helped though.  I am going to try something else and report back.

Comment: steveax, thanks for mentioning that.  I did find some tags in the end result that were not where I placed them in my source.  I was wondering if there was something going like you mentioned.  I am going to try to see if I can rearrange the divs and the forms.

Comment: steveax, I moved my form closing tag below the div for the buttons.  I also moved the "Add Member" form outside of all of that and changed the "Add Member" button to a plain old button with a call to *.submit for that special form in the onclick.  That solved it.  I don't see a "accept comment as answer" link/button, but if there is I will give it to you.  Thanks much.

Comment: @Steve I added the solution in my comment in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There are HTML errors that that will lead to unpredictable rendering, *viz*:

```
<form><!-- Opening form tag somewhere above -->
[...]
<div class="button_bar">
    <div class="button_bar_left_button">     
        <input value="Request More Informtion" name="buttonRequestMoreInformation" type="submit">
    </div>
</form><!-- end form 'f', main form -->  
[...]
</div><!-- end div button_bar -->
```

The browser will correct this error to get a DOM that makes sense by closing the `button_bar` div before the closing `<form>` tag:

```
<form><!-- Opening form tag somewhere above -->
[...]
<div class="button_bar">
    <div class="button_bar_left_button">     
        <input value="Request More Informtion" name="buttonRequestMoreInformation" type="submit">
    </div>
</div><!-- Browser will likely insert a closing tag for .button_bar here to correct the error -->
</form><!-- end form 'f', main form -->  
[...]
<!-- This closing div tag will now be "extra" -->
</div><!-- end div button_bar -->
```